# JS/CSS - Periscope Heart Like Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using this tutorial http://zanilic.com/periscope-likes-tutorial-jquery-css3 (demo: http://zanilic.com/tutorials/periscope-hearts-css3-jquery/)

I'm trying to edit the periscope show heart on click to fit my needs:

- instead of on click, it loops automatically
- instead of spawning from one static spot, it spawns along the bottom of the div in the example
- randomize the rise route (so when it spawns they don't all just follow the same route)

Ive got the automation to work, but I'm a little stuck on the last two.
Would anyone be able to help?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    callme();
});

function hearts() {
  // Init
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  var flows = ["flowOne", "flowTwo", "flowThree"];
  var colors = ["colOne", "colTwo", "colThree", "colFour", "colFive", "colSix"];
  var timing = (Math.random() * (1.3 - 1.0) + 1.0).toFixed(1);
  // Animate Particle
  $(
    '<div class="particle part-' +
      rand +
      " " +
      colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] +
      '" style="font-size:' +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 22) + 22) +
      'px;"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div>'
  )
    .appendTo(".particle-box")
    .css({
      animation:
        "" + flows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " " + timing + "s linear"
    });
  $(".part-" + rand).show();
  // Remove Particle
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".part-" + rand).remove();
  }, timing * 1000 - 100);
};

function callme() {
  hearts();
  setTimeout(callme, 500);
}
```

```css
.particle-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.particle {
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px; 
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}
div.particle i {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    color: red;
}
div.particle i.fa-heart-o {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes flowOne {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 14%;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0%;
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    80% {
        bottom: 80%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 18%;
    }
}
@keyframes flowTwo {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
 }
 40% {
  opacity: 0.8;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 11%;
 }
 60% {
  opacity: 0.2;
 }
 80% {
  bottom: 60%;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 80%;
  left: 0%;
 }
}
@keyframes flowThree {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
 }
 40% {
  opacity: 0.8;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 30%;
 }
 60% {
  opacity: 0.2;
 }
 80% {
  bottom: 70%;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 90%;
  left: 0%;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Start Content -->
<div class="particle-box"></div>
<!-- End Content -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to show animation on click as shown in the demo ?

Comment: No, I want it to run on a loop! I've already achieved this though, and just need help with confining the hearts within the box (so it starts at the bottom and then fades when it's near the top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after a long struggle I found out that these 2 classes were the culprit, here position was relative previously so i make it absolute and increase the height,so hearts are in the box now.

```
div.particle {
    width: 30px; 
    height: 80px; 
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}
div.particle i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    color: red;
}
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    callme();
});

function hearts() {
  // Init
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  var flows = ["flowOne", "flowTwo", "flowThree"];
  var colors = ["colOne", "colTwo", "colThree", "colFour", "colFive", "colSix"];
  var timing = (Math.random() * (1.3 - 1.0) + 1.0).toFixed(1);
  // Animate Particle
  $(
    '<div class="particle part-' +
      rand +
      " " +
      colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)] +
      '" style="font-size:' +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 22) + 22) +
      'px;"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div>'
  )
    .appendTo(".particle-box")
    .css({
      animation:
        "" + flows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + " " + timing + "s linear"
    });
  $(".part-" + rand).show();
  // Remove Particle
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".part-" + rand).remove();
  }, timing * 1000 - 100);
};

function callme() {
  hearts();
  setTimeout(callme, 500);
}
```

```css
.particle-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.particle {
    width: 30px; 
    height: 80px; 
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}
div.particle i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    color: red;
}
div.particle i.fa-heart-o {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes flowOne {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 14%;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0%;
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    80% {
        bottom: 80%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 18%;
    }
}
@keyframes flowTwo {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
 }
 40% {
  opacity: 0.8;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 11%;
 }
 60% {
  opacity: 0.2;
 }
 80% {
  bottom: 60%;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 80%;
  left: 0%;
 }
}
@keyframes flowThree {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
 }
 40% {
  opacity: 0.8;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 30%;
 }
 60% {
  opacity: 0.2;
 }
 80% {
  bottom: 70%;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 90%;
  left: 0%;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Start Content -->
<div class="particle-box"></div>
<!-- End Content -->
```